# Marketing Cloud Android Permissions

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

I have integrated Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK in an Android application.

If I use:

compile 'com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.9.4'

then Permissions that I do not need are added like Bluetooth

and if I use:

compile 'com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.9.4@aar'
(with @aar)

then some Permissions are missing (like Read External Storage) which makes the app crash when a user receives a notification that plays a sound located in his external storage.

I'm not sure which one I should use and what Permissions are automatically added or should be added manually. I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the `android-beacon-library` as indicated in the documentation https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android-v4.9.4/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html.  This would remove the unnecessary BlueTooth permission that is getting included by the library.

```
dependencies {
  compile ('com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.9.+') {
    // exclude module: 'android-beacon-library'
    // exclude module: 'play-services-location'
  }
}
```

If your application is using a media file in external storage then your application will require those permissions, but that is not part of what the SDK requires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do that. Regarding the crash it looks like it is related to the SDK:  com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.h.c
java.lang.SecurityException: External path: /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/notifications/Toinkmp3Powiadomienie.mp3: Neither user 10226 nor current process has android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Again, the SDK does not require these permissions.  If, however, your application is using a notification sound stored in external media then your application will require these permissions.